# named implementation to default implementation

Tags: typeclass, idris

I defined a named implementation for the typeclass Ord for type Int.

```
[mijnOrd] Ord Int where
  compare n1 n2 = ...
```

How can I import this named implementation and use it as "default"

- so in another module I want to import this implementation
- Mark it as default
- And use it as if it was default

--

```
sort [1,5,2] -- output without importing as default: [1,2,5]
sort [1,5,2] -- output with importing as default: [5,2,1]
```

Is this possible in Idris?

Comment: I believe this feature was added in the past year, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Any idea how this feature is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible since Idris 0.12 using `using`-blocks:

Export your named interface in one module, say `MyOrd.idr`:

```
module MyOrd

-- Reverse order for `Nat`
export
[myOrd] Ord Nat where
  compare Z Z = EQ
  compare Z (S k) = GT
  compare (S k) Z = LT
  compare (S k) (S j) = compare @{myOrd} k j
```

Then just import it in another module and wrap everything that should use it as default in a corresponding `using`-block like so:

```
-- Main.idr
module Main

import MyOrd

using implementation myOrd
  test : List Nat -> List Nat
  test = sort

main : IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ test [3, 1, 2]
```

This should print `[3, 2, 1]`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. As far as I understand it, `using implementation` changes the default implementation of the corresponding interface that the compiler picks when you don't provide one explicitly using `@{myOrd}` syntax. Normally the unnamed implementation is chosen.