# Selecting a named implementation in Idris 2

Tags: syntax, typeclass, idris

According to [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38390659/477476), Idris 1 has the `using` syntax to select default implementations for a block of code. What is the corresponding Idris 2 syntax?

I've tried using the syntax from the answer:

```
using implementation Any
  tick1 : Time -> Writer Bool Time
  tick1 t = pure t
```

but this one doesn't even parse:

```
 `-- src/HL2/Clock.idr line 14 col 0:
     Expected end of input.
     
     HL2.Clock:14:1--14:6
      14 | using implementation Any
           ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

`@{name}` syntax allows custom implementations to be passed to functions.

```
[reverseOrd] Ord Nat where
   compare Z (S n)     = GT
   compare (S n) Z     = LT
   compare Z Z         = EQ
   compare (S x) (S y) = compare @{reverseOrd} x y


main : IO ()
main = printLn $ sort @{reverseOrd} [1,2,3,4,5]
```

This prints `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

Comment: Does that mean if I want to use the `Any` monoid with a `Writer` like in my original question, all my terms will need to be polluted with `@{Any}`, e.g. instead of `pure foo` I would have to write `pure @{Any} foo`?

Comment: @Cactus it doesn't give you the whole implementation, just a single method, but you could alias `pure = pure @{Any}` then use `with ModuleName.pure ...`

Comment: @joel but of course in my real code I want to use all kinds of monadic combinators, not just `pure` or not even just a small pre-selected handful of them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on discussions on an Idris community running on an unfortunately proprietary and commercial platform, the best bet seems to be:

1. Bind a name to the desired `Monoid Bool` implementation and mark it as `%hint` so that Idris2 will use it to resolve `Monoid Bool` constraints:

   ```
   %hint
   Any' : Monoid Bool
   Any' = Any
   ```
2. To avoid polluting the module's name space (you might of course have two functions in the same module that wish to use two different `Monoid Bool` implementations), put the whole thing (both the binding of `Any'` and the `Writer`-using definition) in a `namespace`.

Putting it all together, we get:

```
namespace Tick
  %hint
  Any' : Monoid Bool
  Any' = Any

  tick1 : Time -> Writer Bool Time
  tick1 = ...
```

Comment: glad you got an answer, and it may work for you, but I don't feel this would scale. IIUC It's fragile to someone else not putting a different `%hint` in the file, which is a lot easier to do than adding a `using`

Comment: @joel: that's why you put only the relevant `Writer`-using definitions into the `namespace`, and define other things in the smae module outside the `namespace`!